# Define height of one specific table cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableView with two custom cells. I need to to define the height of one cell but leave the other alone. I am trying to learn Objective-C, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your UITableView delegate, implement the routine tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: and return whatever height you want for whatever row. Something like:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if ( indexPath.row == 0 )   // 1st row
     return 25.0;
  else
     return 35.0;
}
```

Comment: This’ll work. Just a note: the default height of a table view cell is 44 points.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks! I was trying something similar with  an if statement but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

To specify the height of a table cell, you need to provide the `UITableViewDelegate` method [`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a).

> I am trying to learn Objective-C, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Your first port of call should be [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/).

Comment: I did take a look but I have always found Apple's way of putting things a but confusing, at least for a guy who's first dive into programing was Objective-C.