# How can change one cell 's height in tableview?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, tableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Define height of one specific table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465213/define-height-of-one-specific-table-cell)

How can change one cell 's height in tableview?
I want to changed one cell 's height in tableview, not init in first time, but also the cell has shown.

Comment: @JackHumphries I am not want to set cell height first time. After the cell is shown, I want change the cell's height again. It's the same way?

Comment: Yes, it is the same way. When you are ready to change the cell's height, simply call `[self.tableView reloadData]` or `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths...]` and pass the correct value for the height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @JackHumphries reload will clear content that already in the cell. Is that any method can change its height but not reinit it?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the height of cells in tableview:hightOfRowAtIndexPath:.

For eg:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat retVal =0.0f;

    if(indexPath.section==//the section you want )
    {
        if(indexPath.row==//the row you want)
        {
            retVal=10.0f;//the height you want.
        }
        else
            retVal=50.0f;
    }
    else 
        retVal=50.0f;

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: I am not want to set cell height first time. After the cell is shown, I want change the cell's height again. It's the same way? @Rob

Comment: @ZhouQi You would (a) have your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` check some ivar for whether it should use the standard height or whether it should use the expanded height; and (b) once you set that ivar, you'd just call [`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)

Comment: @Rob reload rows will clear the cell 's content.

Comment: @Rob my cell has a textview, and I want when input some content into textview, the textview will become more than one line. so the cell 's height need become big too.

Comment: You just need to set a BOOL variable.If you need the height changed just set the BOOL and reloadRowsAtIndexPath to change the height.If you want to change the height according to the textview text you can set the BOOL in textView's delegate method (for e.g.: textViewDidChange:) and call reloadRows.. in that when you want to increase the height.

Comment: @ZhouQi You said "reload rows will clear the cell's content". It won't if you save the current textview value in some ivar (or somewhere in your model) and make sure that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` grabs it.

Comment: @Rob I found tableview's beginUpdates and endUpdates can just update height without reload.

Comment: @ZhouQi Glad you found a solution.